# Can you extend a sumifs formula dependent on an if statement?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, sumifs

I'm wondering if it is possible to extend a SUMIFS formula dependent on an IF statement.

In the example below, what I want is if $O$5 = 0, to extend the SUMIFS formula so that the ">0" becomes criteria1 and then a new criteria_range2 is created, with "<10" as criteria2.

Looking at 'evaluate formula', I'm not sure if the issue is that it won't read the extended bit because it isn't possible to do this, or if the CHAR(34) aren't showing up as I hoped.

> =SUMIFS('Revenue'!$G$1:$G$100,'Revenue'!$H$1:$H$100,IF($O$5=0,CHAR(34)&">0"&CHAR(34)&","&"'Revenue'!$H$1:$H$100"&","&CHAR(34)&"<10"&CHAR(34),$O$5))

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to use `SUMIFs`, it should be something like this:

**way №1**

```
=SUMIFS(Revenue!$G$1:$G$100,Revenue!$H$1:$H$100,IF($O$5=0,">0",$O$5),
                            Revenue!$H$1:$H$100,IF($O$5=0,"<10",$O$5)
 )
```

If `O5=0`, formula evaluates to:

```
=SUMIFS(Revenue!$G$1:$G$100,Revenue!$H$1:$H$100,">0",
                            Revenue!$H$1:$H$100,"<10"
 )
```

If `O5<>0`, formula evaluates to:

```
=SUMIFS(Revenue!$G$1:$G$100,Revenue!$H$1:$H$100,$O$5,
                            Revenue!$H$1:$H$100,$O$5
 )
```

which is actually gives you the same result as

```
=SUMIFS(Revenue!$G$1:$G$100,Revenue!$H$1:$H$100,$O$5)
```

---

**way №2**

```
=IF($O$5=0,
  SUMIFs(Revenue!$G$1:$G$100,Revenue!$H$1:$H$100,">0",
                             Revenue!$H$1:$H$100,"<10"),
  SUMIFs(Revenue!$G$1:$G$100,Revenue!$H$1:$H$100,$O$5)
 )
```

If `O5=0`, formula evaluates to:

```
=SUMIFS(Revenue!$G$1:$G$100,Revenue!$H$1:$H$100,">0",
                            Revenue!$H$1:$H$100,"<10"
 )
```

If `O5<>0`, formula evaluates to:

```
=SUMIFS(Revenue!$G$1:$G$100,Revenue!$H$1:$H$100,$O$5)
```

---

**way №3**

Or you can use sumproduct as well:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Revenue!$G$1:$G$100)*
            IF($O$5=0,(Revenue!$H$1:$H$100>0)*(Revenue!$H$1:$H$100<10),
                      (Revenue!$H$1:$H$100=$O$5)
            )
 )
```

This is an *array formula*, so type the formula then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Curly brackets will automatically appear at the start and end of the formula.

If `O5=0`, formula evaluates to:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Revenue!$G$1:$G$100)*(Revenue!$H$1:$H$100>0)*
                                  (Revenue!$H$1:$H$100<10)
 )
```

If `O5<>0`, formula evaluates to:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Revenue!$G$1:$G$100)*(Revenue!$H$1:$H$100=$O$5))
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Classic case of me over complicating things.
Is there any benefits of using the sumproduct method? I've steered clear of array formulas as long as there has been a simpler way of doing something.

Comment: Actually, sumproduct is the slowest formula in my answer. I just left it because it's closets to your attempts, but I don't recommend you to use it.

Comment: I thought that was the case.  Thanks for confirming!